# Get the content of a text box from a class library (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class-library

I have a project in C# with Visual Studio. I used a Windows Form to create my application.

In this project, I created a class library with all my classes. My problem is that if I want to get the value or write in a text box of my Windows Form, I can't access the element.

For understanding, I have this :

[image]

In the class "Classe", I want to get a value like this :

```
TextBoxTables.Text
```

But I can't access the Windows Form, what should I do please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to call the method you want to use that text box, send the textbox as a parameter. Just like this:

```
public void MyMethod(TextBox t){
// ...
}
```

And call it like this:

```
Classe cls = new Classe();
cls.MyMethod(TextBoxTables);
```

So You'll have it.

Comment: You don't need to pass the entire TextBox to the class library if you only want to read the value. Just pass the value of the textbox to the method.This way you don't have to add a WinForms reference to the class library.

Comment: @Alex what he wants is


> get the value or write in a text box 
.
Both. So he may need the text box

Comment: Ok, I understand but now, I can't get my TextBox from my main. Did I forgot a "using" (I have those using System.Windows.Forms;
using ClassLibrary;)

Comment: @MohammadMirMostafa but still, if he needs to update the text box value, he can write in the WinForms... textBox1.Text = libraryClass.DoSomethingWithString(textBox1.Text) and update it this way.

Comment: @Erlaunis Good to know you got the answer and it worked. However, try not to mix UI and non-UI code in the future. It's a bad practice.

Comment: Really ? I didn't know, why ?

Comment: @Erlaunis because that way you have less spaghetti code. It's easier to troubleshoot, easier to change UI. The whole point of class libraries is to contain logic. Then you can re-use it with other solution or implement different UI without touching the code in class library ;) *in theory of course*

Comment: I get it. In my case, I just want to display the state of my program. It's a program which simulate a chairs and tables' factory, and in a textbox, I want to display "Chair 1 construct : Done !" or something like that. But the function of the fabrication is in the class library. Is there an other way to do it ?

Comment: Hi ! I'm sorry, but I have some problem about the same thing, can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

Normally the relationship between a class library and a WinForms project is when WinForms application references the class library. Therefore, you cannot read data written in text box from a class library.

Consider calling a method in a class library and passing the value of text box to that method.

That way you won't create dependency on your WinForms textbox inside the class library.